# Android Studio build failed: TIRAMISU and PackageInfoFlags not found

Tags: android-studio

I have a clean install of Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 with Gradle 7.4.2.
Running a build of my app (that had worked fine before) throws these two errors found in InternalUtils.java file:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable TIRAMISU
  location: class VERSION_CODES

error: cannot find symbol
            return pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.PackageInfoFlags.of(flags));
                                                                ^
  symbol:   variable PackageInfoFlags
  location: class PackageManager
```

This is the code section in the *InternalUtils.java* file failing with these two lines:

[image]

My build.gradle specs are:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 22
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
    }
```

These are my SDK packages installed:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, there is no *Android API 33* entry listed in the SDK Platforms list, so I can't install it. Why is there no API 33 available?

Also, in the SDK Tools list, there is no *Android SDK Build-Tools 33* entry (as there is one for 34).

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your import **Build**. 
It should be like `android.os.Build`


Also try installing **compileSdkVersion  34**

Comment: Thanks, Ivan. I changed in build.gradle to: compileSdkVersion = 34 - no change. This is an Angular application, so I don't know if importing android.os.Build is relevant, or I don't understand something here.

Comment: are you converting an angular app to a native app? is it some kind of JS framework?

Comment: Yes, Angular is a front-end framework. I build the app and then using capacitor  I build the native Android and IOS app. Then, in Android Studio I just run the build with gradle and generate the apk/aab files or directly install to device.

Comment: Capacitor 5 needs `compileSdkVersion = 33`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was only solved by downgrading some of the Capacitor plugins. Here's what solved it eventually:

I downgraded the following to @latest-4:
"@capacitor/android": "^4.8.1",
"@capacitor/app": "^4.1.1",
"@capacitor/camera": "^4.1.5",
"@capacitor/cli": "^4.8.1",
"@capacitor/push-notifications": "^4.1.2",

Also, I had to set the Android Gradle plugin version to 7.4.2 in the Project Properties (downgrading from 8.0.2 after tried to upgrade it to 8.0.2).
Also, had to set in the gradle-wrapper.properties to 7.5: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was stuck with different versions from long. Changing my cap versions to above worked for me.